# Invalid block type while accessing the custom block (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, module, custom-block

Error in **magento 2.0.11** while accessing **custom block**

```
Invalid block type: Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Block\Customizepage
#0 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(237): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('Tomrain\\Appcust...', Array)
#1 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(215): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('Tomrain\\Appcust...', 'customizepage', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'customizepage')
#3 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#4 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#5 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(89): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#6 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements()
#7 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#9 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(187): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#10 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#11 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(170): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild()
#12 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/App/View.php(114): Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayoutUpdates()
#13 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/app/code/Tomrain/Appcustomizer/Controller/Customize/index.php(20): Magento\Framework\App\View->loadLayout()
#14 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/var/generation/Tomrain/Appcustomizer/Controller/Customize/index/Interceptor.php(24): Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\Index->execute()
#15 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor->execute()
#16 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#19 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Tomrain\\Appcust...', 'dispatch', Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Array, 'designLoader')
#20 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/Design.php(39): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\Design->aroundDispatch(Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Tomrain\\Appcust...', 'dispatch', Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Array, 'contextPlugin')
#24 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/Context.php(106): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\Context->aroundDispatch(Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#27 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Tomrain\\Appcust...', 'dispatch', Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Array, 'customer-app-ac...')
#28 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(61): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#29 [internal function]: Magento\Customer\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#31 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Tomrain\\Appcust...', 'dispatch', Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Array, 'storeCheck')
#32 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/Action/Plugin/StoreCheck.php(44): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\Action\Plugin\StoreCheck->aroundDispatch(Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#35 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Tomrain\\Appcust...', 'dispatch', Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Array, 'weee-app-action...')
#36 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/module-weee/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(112): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 [internal function]: Magento\Weee\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#39 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Tomrain\\Appcust...', 'dispatch', Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Array, 'tax-app-action-...')
#40 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php(91): Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#41 [internal function]: Magento\Tax\Model\App\Action\ContextPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#42 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#43 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/var/generation/Tomrain/Appcustomizer/Controller/Customize/index/Interceptor.php(39): Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#44 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize\index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#47 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#48 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'requestPreproce...')
#49 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(89): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#50 [internal function]: Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#52 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#53 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#54 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#55 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#56 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#57 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#58 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#59 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#60 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#61 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#62 [internal function]: Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#63 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#64 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#65 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#66 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#67 /var/www/html/appcustomizer-tshirt-M2/index.php(42): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#68 {main}
```

When the url passed in the address bar it reaches up to controller action.Problem in `$this->_view->loadLayout();`

**app/code/Tomrain/Appcustomizer/Controller/Customize/index.php**

```
namespace Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Controller\Customize;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\File\UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory
        )
    {
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    } 
}
```

**app/code/Tomrain/Appcustomizer/view/frontend/layout/appcustomizer_customize_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Block\Customizepage" name="customizepage" template="Tomrain_Appcustomizer::customize/productcustomize.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Tomrain/Appcustomizer/Block/Customizepage.php**

```
namespace Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Block;

class Customizepage extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Tomrain\Appcustomizer\Helper\Data $helper
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->helper->getBaseUrl();
    }

    public function getConfigUrl()
    {
        $ConfigUrl =  $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('web/unsecure/base_url', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        return $ConfigUrl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your site in production or development, have you tried deleteing var/generation, have you flushed the cache

Answer (score 0):

Each block takes `array $data = []` as parameter.(conventionally included at last)
Hence when you call parent constructor it should look something like this 
`parent::__construct($context, $data);` Change that and let me know.

Comment: Can you double check folder name with small and capital letter.

Comment: I have passed `array $data = []` as parameter in __construct and changed `parent::__construct($context, $data);`but is not working

Comment: Does it give you same error?

Comment: yes it gives same error.

Comment: Now we need to find out if it is able to find the class. What happens if you do new <Your block class>() in your controller. If it throws class not found error then there is some typo in folder name or something because autoloader can not load. If not this then change your block class in layout to Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template if the error persists then the way you are creating the block is the problem and you should use pagefactory object to create the view

Comment: I have found the error by running `setup:di:compile` command. Error in helper file                                                                                                       `public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ) ` i.e. added extra comma after secound parameter.I have injected helper file in block file so the error occured

Answer (score 0):

Just flush, check permission ...I fixed by:

sudo php bin/magento cache:flush 
sudo chmod 777 -R generated/* var/* pub/*

Comment: chmod 777 is not secure